# Displaying Dataset Query and Report Expressions in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports-2010

I am switching from Crystal Reports to SSRS Reporting. In Crystal Reports, there was a way to display the Selection Criteria at the end of each report. This displayed all of the data manipulations made by the developer to the report data. 
Example:(this would be displayed at the end of each report in Crystal)

Selection Criteria: 
    `usp.Members.MemberID <>2 and 
    usp.Members.Active = "Y" and 
    if(usp.Members.Location = "M1" then "Admission Location" else " ")`

In SSRS I am able to manipulate the data in a number of places; Query Builder in the Dataset Properties, Textbox/Field Expressions, and via Filters.

Is there any any that I can display all the report expressions I have made, or display the query used to generate the dataset, at the end of the report to show the user the logic behind the data?

I understand what I am asking could be difficult to understand. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view the Dataset query using an expression like:

```
=DataSets!DataSet1.CommandText
```

Where `DataSet1` is the name of your Dataset.

To give an example, say I have a report with the query:

[image]

I have a simple report based on this:

[image]

You can see the textbox expression is the same as above:

[image]

The expression is showing an error but this works anyway:

[image]

See [What DataSet Query Text Is Executed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/25/what-dataset-query-text-is-executed.aspx) for more information.

Not sure on extracting all expressions from the report, but hopefully this will be enough.

**Edit after comment**

OP mentions that it is only working for him in the report header, but in my example this is working in the body.

From [Using Built-in Collections in Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157274.aspx) it seems like there are some further restrictions here:

> Represents the collection of datasets referenced from the body of a
>   report definition. Does not include data sources used only in page
>   headers or page footers. Not available in local preview.

Which explains why it was working for me - it was also being used in a table.

As a simple workaround you could simply add a hidden textbox somewhere on the report body that references the required Dataset; this should allow `.CommandText` to work in the body.

Comment: Thank you. This did work, but only when I inserted the textbox and expression into the Header. Is it possible to display this inside the report body, after a tablix item to show the query on the last page of the report?

Comment: Hmm, you can see it worked for me - I've added some suggestions about why this might happen and a suggested workaround.